# How to populate <form:select> with List<String>?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have a `List<String>` in the controller which im passing to the view. I need to populate `<form:select>` with that data.

I tried setting the `itemValue` attribute to `"name"` but that did not work.

Comment: Which `<form:select>` is this?  Spring MVC?  Either way, show us your code; we can't guess what you're doing from short descriptions.

Comment: That's not JSTL. To learn what JSTL is, read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
<form:select path="selectName">
    <form:option value="0" label="Select an Option" />
    <form:options items="${nameOfList}" />
</form:select>
```

By providing only the items attribute to the form:options tag, it should make the value and label the value of each String in your list.

Comment: Perfect, It's running like a charm.

Answer (score 7):

you can also try as follows:

```
<form:select path="country">
<form:option value="NONE" label="--- Select ---" />
<form:options items="${countryList}" itemValue="value" itemLabel="description"/>
</form:select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
protected Map referenceData(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
Map referenceData = new HashMap();
Map<String,String> country = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
country.put("US", "United Stated");
country.put("CHINA", "China");
country.put("SG", "Singapore");
country.put("MY", "Malaysia");
referenceData.put("countryList", country);
```

}

Then

```
<form:select path="country" items="${countryList}" />
```